# When to use the private key during Google OAuth workflow?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm building an OAuth based workflow to secure some resources and I'm wondering if the secret client key provided by Google is really useful for other things than signin JSON Web Token (JWT).

Currently I'm collecting user response from my front-end app with the `access_token`, which seems enough to authentify an user. I got all the details I need and a server side verification of the token.

Is there something I'm currently missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Client Secret is used to identify your app / website for Google OAuth 2.0. The Client Secret would not mean anything outside of Google Services.

In your questions comment's you asked is it safe to send the access token to the server. If you have implemented Google OAuth 2.0 correctly, your server was sent the access token as part of the authentication flow. There is no need to send the token from the client to the server as the server already has it (you should have saved the Access Token, Refresh Token and Client ID Token after authentication as part of client session state). During the authorization, the user granted your app / website permission to use the scopes that you requested.

You do not specify what type of access token you are using or how it was created. If instead your access token was derived from a Signed-JWT from your own internal mechanism's then my commments regarding Google OAuth 2.0 do not apply and it is up to your server's logic to create, control and manage the tokens.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very detailled answer, the `access_token` comes from an embedded Google Authentication iframe, and I'm sending this access_token generated to the server to generate an unique identity within my system (so checking server side the access_token validity) with custom permissions and rules available to end user through a server signed JWT. In other words, I'm extending existing authentication workflow to get a centralized authorization platform and providing it as a service to end users.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need **client_secret** to exchange **access_token**, I assume your current app use **authorization code** grant type to exchange **access_token** which is don't need **client_secret**, only **redirect_uri** and **client_id** because you can't store **client_secret** securely in pure front-end app.

There are other grant type  in oauth2, for example **Client Credential**  (mostly use by server app), you need to provide **client_id** and **client_secret** to exchange access_token.

You can read more about oauth-2 grant type [here](https://oauth.net/2/)

Comment: Is there any risk sending access_token to server rather than using an approach with client_secret? Thanks for your response

Comment: As long as long your communication with server is secure you should be good to send out the access_Token to server.

Comment: no, because in **authorization code** grant type **access_token** is only belong to authorization user, that mean you can't use that **access_token** to get other user's resource. 

you can't use **client_secret** to access resource, **client_secret** is used when you want to exchange **access_token**